# Python: Spaces to Tabs?

Tags: python, linux

I have a python file (`/home/test.py`) that has a mixture of spaces and tabs in it.

Is there a programmatic way (note: **programmatic**, NOT using an editor) to convert this file to use only tabs? (meaning, replace any existing `4-spaces` occurrences with a single `tab`)?

Would be grateful for either a python code sample or a linux command to do the above. Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to convert 4 spaces to tabs. This is against PEP-8. 4 spaces is the standard - also for you :) Apart from that: look at the tabcleaner.py script of Python and rip the related code from there.

Comment: @Javier: thank you. Was not sure how to apply it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a task for `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/    /\t/g' test.py > test.new
```

[Put a real tab instead of \t]

However...

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

--[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @user540009: I hope you refer to PEP 8 :-)

Comment: thank you. Just for the record, how would you replace every single 'tab' with 4-spaces? (what is the reverse `sed` command)?

Comment: @user540009: 's/\t/    /g' (with a tab before the middle slash and four spaces after) is the reverse. Or you could use Python's [`expandtabs()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/string.html#string.expandtabs)

Comment: if anyone else is having trouble actually typing a tab, `sed -e $'s/    /\t/g'` will make the switch with the `\t` expanded to a real tab character :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try iterating the file and doing replacing eg

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    print line.replace("    ","\t")
```

or you can try a *nix tool like `sed/awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/    /,"\t")}1' file > temp && mv temp file

$ ruby -i.bak -ne '$_.gsub!(/    /,"\t")' file
```

Comment: Good answer, although the one liner below was better.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is by installing the [black-with-tabs](https://pypi.org/project/black-with-tabs/) package.
And run black (you need to uninstall if you already have the original black installed)

```
black test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do is replace the *leading* spaces with tabs.

Most of the answers here are replacing all spaces with tabs, which might not be the correct thing to do in most cases.

```py
def tabify(line, tab_size):
    return line.replace(" " * tab_size, "\t", (len(line) - len(line.lstrip(" "))) // tab_size)

def tabify_fd(old, new, tab_size):
    new.writelines(tabify(line) for line in old.readline())

def tabify_file(old, new, tab_size):
    with open(old, "r") as old_fd:
        with open(new, "w") as new_fd:
            tabify_fd(old_fd, new_fd, tab_size)
```

See [Using a single replacement operation replace all leading tabs with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039515)