# Using a single replacement operation replace all leading tabs with spaces

Tags: python, regex

In my text I want to replace all leading tabs with two spaces but leave the non-leading tabs alone.

For example:

```
a
\tb
\t\tc
\td\te
f\t\tg
```

(`"a\n\tb\n\t\tc\n\td\te\nf\t\tg"`)

should turn into:

```
a
  b
    c
  d\te
f\t\tg
```

(`"a\n  b\n    c\n  d\te\nf\t\tg"`)

For my case I could do that with multiple replacement operations, repeating as many times as the many maximum nesting level or until nothing changes.

**But wouldn't it also be possible to do in a single run?**

I tried but didn't manage to come up with something, the best I came up yet was with lookarounds:

```
re.sub(r'(^|(?<=\t))\t', '  ', a, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Which "only" makes one wrong replacement (second tab between `f` and `g`).

Now it might be that it's simply impossible to do in regex in a single run because the already replaced parts can't be matched again (or rather the replacement does not happen right away) and you can't sort-of "count" in regex, in this case I would love to see some more detailed explanations on why (as long as this won't shift too much into [cs.se] territory).

I am working in Python currently but this could apply to pretty much any similar regex implementation.

Comment: Why not just `.strip()` each line?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I want to replace the `\t`s, not remove them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may match the tabs at the start of the lines, and use a lambda inside `re.sub` to replace with the double spaces multiplied by the length of the match:

```
import re
s = "a\n\tb\n\t\tc\n\td\te\nf\t\tg";
print(re.sub(r"^\t+", lambda m: "  "*len(m.group()), s, flags=re.M))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AmOECe)

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to do this without regex using `replace()` in a one liner:

```
>>> s = "a\n\tb\n\t\tc\n\td\te\nf\t\tg"
>>> "\n".join(x.replace("\t","  ",len(x)-len(x.lstrip("\t"))) for x in s.split("\n"))
'a\n  b\n    c\n  d\te\nf\t\tg'
```

Answer (score 1):

This here is kinda crazy, but it works:

```
"\n".join([ re.sub(r"^(\t+)"," "*(2*len(re.sub(r"^(\t+).*","\1",x))),x) for x in "a\n\tb\n\t\tc\n\td\te\nf\t\tg".splitlines() ])
```